# Php Redirect to a new page from an if statement

Tags: php, url, redirect, header

Please professional programmers in the house, what is wrong with this code?

I get this error whenever i try to run it.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\a\go.php on line 8

The php code:

```
<?php

$term=$_POST['term'];
$level=$_POST['level'];

if  (

$term = 'First';
$level='js1';

)
{
header("Location: result.php");
exit();
} 
elseif (
$term = 'First';
$level='js2'; 
)
{
header("Location: result2.php");
exit();
} 

else {
$error = "Entry is invalid";
}

?>
```

Comment: [Read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) on the IF statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your if condition. The if and else if conditions must not contain any semicolons. If you are using two comparisons you must use && or || in between them. If you are using = in the if and elseif statement then it will always return true.

```
<?php

$term=$_POST['term'];
$level=$_POST['level'];

if  ($term == 'First' && $level=='js1')
  {
    header("Location: result.php");
    exit();
  } 
else if ($term == 'First' && $level='js2')
  {
    header("Location: result2.php");
    exit();
  } 
else {
  $error = "Entry is invalid";
}

?>
```

Comment: Great! Worked. Thank you

Comment: Could do with some explanation as to what the issue is and how to fix it, apart from that good job with fixing this mess.

Answer (score 2):

Change your if condition

it should be

```
if($term = 'First'&& $level='js1') or if($term = 'First'|| $level='js1') 

   elseif ($term = 'First' && $level='js2') or elseifif($term = 'First'|| $level='js2')
```

not

```
if  ($term = 'First'; $level='js1';)

elseif ($term = 'First' ; $level='js2';)
```

Comment: The `elseif` is also wrong. Maybe worth mentioning that also

Answer (score 1):

All of your `if` statements have a malformed format. All you are doing is setting variables within your `if` statement. Therefore you are not using assignment operators properly. An example of how your `if` statement should look is:

```
if($condition === true || $condition2 == 'hello'){
    doSomething();
} else if($condition === false || $condtion2 == 'bye'){
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

EDIT: Also i would recommend working on your code indentation skills, this will really help to read your code in the future.

Comment: This is the best answer. Not just writing code for the asker. but explaining why it is not working.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, I try to always use the `give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime` philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

You are not making correct boolean expressions in those ifs.

```
if ($term === 'first' && $level === 'js1') {...}

elseif($term === 'First' && $level === 'js2') {...}
```

Also, I strongly recommend you to put a die(); after a redirect to avoid unnecessary load (unless you need to execute code after the redirect).

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
<?php

    $term=$_POST['term'];
    $level=$_POST['level'];

    if( $term == 'First' && $level=='js1'){
        header("Location: result.php");
        exit();
    } elseif ( $term == 'First' && $level=='js2'){
        header("Location: result2.php");
        exit();
    } else {
        $error = "Entry is invalid";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

If there is a header already sent error you receive then put ob_start() to top of your php file OR You can also use javascript for this like below.

```
<script>window.location.href = "a.php";</script>
```